# Http request on NativeScript not working after add Arbitrary Loads on Info.plist

Tags: ios, http, angular, typescript, nativescript

I'm getting starting with NativeScript, actually I'm doing the Quickstart.

- *[here is the page](http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-1)*

I read on a similar question that it's necessary enable the http request from Info.plist, this is the content of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Groceries</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>api.everlive.com</key>
            <string></string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Screen of the file:
[image]

But when I run the app just don't work on iOS platform:
 [image]

This is the console output:

```
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/shared/user/user.service.ts:50:20: {"line":40,"column":37,"sourceURL":"file:///app/tns_modules/http/http-request.js"}
```

Supposedly the app should work with the lines added on Info.plist, any idea about what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> Looks like iOS doesn't support this kind of concatenation only Android
>   does:
>
> - **`${variable}/some-data`**
>
> On the http request it's necessary do it in the `classic` way:
>
> - **variable+'/some-data'**